# How to run test cases with given custom annotation

Tags: java, testing, reflection, junit

I want to run integration tests only if it has given annotation. The thing is that test cases need some variables which are needed to be initialized in `@Before` and destroyed in `@After`.

I wrote the code which executes the tests which have given annotation, but they all fail because of the variables which need to be initialized in `@Before` phase.

I first invoke `@Before` phase(I suppose the variables are initialized), then run the test method, then invoke `@After` phase. But I get `NullPointerException` in test method.

How to initialize variable for the test methods?? Isn't enough to invoke **@Before** phase??

The code I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class<TodoMapperTest> obj = TodoMapperTest.class;

    int passed = 0;
    int failed = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (Method method : obj.getDeclaredMethods()) {
      if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Before.class))
        method.invoke(obj.newInstance());

      if (method.isAnnotationPresent(DEV.class)) {
        try {
          method.invoke(obj.newInstance());
          System.out.printf("%s - Test '%s' - passed %n", ++count, method.getName());
          passed++;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
          System.out.printf("%s - Test '%s' - failed: %s %n", ++count, method.getName(), ex);
          failed++;
        }
      }

      if (method.isAnnotationPresent(After.class))
        method.invoke(obj.newInstance());
    }

    System.out.printf("%nResult : Total : %d, Passed: %d, Failed %d%n", count, passed, failed);
  }
```

**`@Before` phase:**

```
TodoQueryMapper mapper;
SqlSession session;

@Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    InputStream inputStream = Resources.getResourceAsStream("todo-mybatis/mybatis-test.xml");
    SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(inputStream);
    inputStream.close();

    session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
    mapper = session.getMapper(TodoQueryMapper.class);
  }
```

**Edit:**
**Test case:**

```
@Test
@DEV
public void test_case() throws Exception {
  SqlParams params = new SqlParams();
  params.idList = Collections.singletonList(1234567);

  // In here, 'mapper' variable is null, even @Before invoked
  List<TodoDto> data = mapper.findByIdList(params); 

  assertEquals(1, data.size());
}
```

**DEV Annotation:**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface DEV {
}
```

Comment: Show your test method please.

Comment: Du you know [JUnit's @Category support](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Categories)? It looks like you're building something very similar.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you invoke a method via reflection you create a new instance of your test class: `method.invoke(obj.newInstance());`

You should seperate your test execution in three phases: Before, Test and After. Iterate over the Test-methods, find the Before- and After-method and execute them in the desired order.

Pseudo code:

```
Class<AccountDaoMapperTest> objClass = AccountDaoMapperTest.class;
for (Method testMethod : findTestMethods(objClass)) {
    AccountDaoMapperTest objUnderTest = objClass.newInstance();
    findBeforeMethod(objClass).invoke(objUnderTest);
    testMethod.invoke(objUnderTest);
    findAfterMethod(objClass).invoke(objUnderTest);
}
```